# Why getting too many re-renders error in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, use-state, react-state

I have a homepage component in react.js . This component gets props from the app component(one of them being userName). When the user enters his name on this page,the `user` variable gets its value updated and correspondingly the setusername function calls the `setUserName` in the App component.I am getting too many re-renders error in the following code:

Homepage component:

```
import React from 'react'
import './homepage.css'
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
const Homepage = (props) => {
    const [user,setUser]=useState("");
    function setUserName()
    {
        const {username,setusername}=props;
        setusername(user);
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <div className="panel">
            <div className="pricing-plan">
                <img src="../images/girly.gif" className="logo" alt=""/>
                <ul className="pricing-features">
                    <h1 className="greetname">Hi, I'm Sam</h1>
                    <li className="pricing-features-item1">What's your name?</li>
                    <input className="pricing-features-item2" name="username" value={user} onChange={(e)=>setUser(e.target.value)}
                        placeholder="A nickname you prefer..."></input>
                </ul>

                <button className="pricing-button" onClick={()=>setUserName()}>Enter</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Homepage
```

App component

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Homepage from './Pages/Homepage';
import Mainpage from './Pages/Mainpage'
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
function App() {
  const [userName,setUserName]=useState(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' exact element={<Homepage username={userName} setusername={setUserName()} />}></Route>
        <Route path='/home' exact element={<Homepage/>}></Route>
        <Route path='/mainpage' exact element={<Mainpage/>}></Route>
      </Routes>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The function `setUserName` seems kinda pointless? If you're passing a state update function through props, just call the prop directly.

Comment: @evolutionxbox what should i do to update the name there?

Comment: @VatsalAMehta - The problem is in `App` where you have `setusername={setUserName()}`. That **calls** `setUserName` and uses its return value for `setusername`.

Comment: Use the prop. `onClick={()=>props.setusername(user)}>`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Im getting this error :```Uncaught TypeError: props.setusername is not a function```

Comment: Did you do what T.J. Crowder and I said?

Comment: Yup its now working